# Really weird HTTP client using TcpClient in C#

Tags: .net, tcp, webserver, httpclient, telnet

I am implementing a simple HTTP Client that just connects to a web server and gets its default homepage. Here it is and it works nice:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient tc = new TcpClient();
            tc.Connect("www.google.com", 80);

            using (NetworkStream ns = tc.GetStream())
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ns);
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ns);

                string req = "";
                req += "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n";
                req += "Host: www.google.com\r\n";
                req += "\r\n";

                sw.Write(req);
                sw.Flush();

                Console.WriteLine("[reading...]");
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
            tc.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("[done!]");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

---

When I delete the below line from above code, the program blocks on **sr.ReadToEnd**.

```
req += "Host: www.google.com\r\n";
```

I even replaced **sr.ReadToEnd** with **sr.Read**, but it cannot read anything. I used Wireshark to see what's happen:

[Screenshot of captured packets using Wireshark http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1252514718052893500.jpg](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1252514718052893500.jpg)

As you see, after my GET request Google doesn't respond and the request is retransmitted again and again. It seems we HAVE TO specify the **Host** part in HTTP request. The weird part is WE DON'T. I used **telnet** to send this request and got the respond from Google. I also captured the request sent by telnet and it was exactly same as my request.

I tried many other websites (e.g. Yahoo, Microsoft) but the result is same.

So, does the delay in telnet cause the web-server act differently (because in telnet we actually *type* characters instead of sending them together in 1 packet).

---

Another weird problem is when I change **HTTP/1.0** to **HTTP/1.1**, the program always blocks on **sr.ReadToEnd** line. I guess that's because the web server don't close the connection.

One solution is using **Read** (or **ReadLine**) and **ns.DataAvailable** to read the response. But I cannot be sure that I have read all of the response. How I can read the response and be sure there is no more bytes left in the response of a HTTP/1.1 request?

---

**Note:**
As W3 says,

> [the **Host** request-header field MUST accompany all **HTTP/1.1**
>   requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

(and I did it for my HTTP/1.1 requests). But I haven't seen such thing for **HTTP/1.0**. Also sending a request without **Host** header using telnet works without any problem.

---

**Update:**

**Push** flag has been set to 1 in the TCP segment. I also have tried **netsh winsock reset** to reset my TCP/IP stack. There is no firewalls nor anti-viruses on the testing computer. The packet are actually sent because Wireshark installed on another computer can capture it.

I also have tried some other requests. For Instance,

```
string req = "";
req += "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n";
req += "s df slkjfd sdf/ s/fd \\sdf/\\\\dsfdsf \r\n";
req += "qwretyuiopasdfghjkl\r\n";
req += "Host: www.google.com\r\n";
req += "\r\n";
```

In all kind of requests, if I omit the **Host:** part, the web-server doesn't respond and if with a **Host:** part, even an invalid request (just like the above request) will be responded (by a 400: HTTP Bad Request).

[nos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126769/nos) says the **Host:** part is not required on his machine, and this makes the situation more weird.

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but shouldn't you use the content-length in the HTTP response to determine how many bytes you should read, and then read those many bytes from the response's body?

Comment: @Aziz. Maybe this is a good solution instead of using **ReadToEnd**. But in the first part of question i don't receive anything (even one byte) from the server.

Comment: That code works here with or without the Host: header. Do the TCP segment of GET request set the PUSH bit ? - not that you can do much about it but if it's not set it could explain the retransmissions

Comment: @nos - Thanks nos. i added some details about your hint

Comment: @Aziz - something to keep in mind is that not all HTTP responses in HTTP 1.1 use a "Content-Length" header at all.  Some responses use a "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header instead, which requires a completely different reading model.

Comment: Guys, Telnet certainly wouldn't send \r\n to host instead of \n.

Answer (score 3):

This pertains to using TcpClient.

I know this post is old. I am providing this information just in case anyone else comes across this. Consider this answer a supplement to all of the above answers.

The HTTP host header is required by some servers since they are setup to host more than one domain per IP address. As a general rule, always sent the Host header. A good server will reply with "Not Found". Some servers won't reply at all.

When the call to read data from the stream blocks, it's usually because the server is waiting for more data to be sent. This is typically the case when the HTTP 1.1 spec is not followed closely. To demonstrate this, try omitting the final CR LF sequence and then read data from the stream - the call to read will wait until either the client times out or the server gives up waiting by terminating the connection.

I hope this sheds a bit of light...

Answer (score 2):

I found one question in all that:

*How i can read the response and be sure i read all of the response in HTTP/1.1 request?*

And that is a question I can answer!

All the methods you're using here are synchronous, which is easy to use but not even slightly reliable.  You'll see problems as soon as you have a sizable response and only get part of it.

To implement a TcpClient connection most robustly, you should use all asynchronous methods and callbacks.  The relevant methods are as follows:

1) Create the connection with TcpClient.BeginConnect(...) with the callback calling TcpClient.EndConnect(...)
2) Send a request with TcpClient.GetStream().BeginWrite(...) with the callback calling TcpClient.GetStream().EndWrite(...)
3) Receive a response with TcpClient.GetStream().BeginRead(...) with the callback calling TcpClient.GetStream().EndRead(...), appending the result to a StringBuilder buffer, and then calling TcpClient.GetStream().BeginRead(...) again (with the same callback) until a response of 0 bytes is received.

It's that final step (repeatedly calling BeginRead until 0 bytes are read) that solves the problem of fetching the response, the whole response, and nothing but the response.  So help us TCP.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try your code against a standard, well tested, largely accepted web server installed on your own local machine, such as Apache HTTPD, or IIS.

Configure your web server to respond without the *Host* header (e.g. a default web application in IIS) and see if all goes well.

At the bottom line, you can't really tell what goes on behind the scenes, since you don't control web sites / web applications like google, yahoo, etc.
For instance, a web site administrator can configure the site so that there's no default application for incoming TCP connections on port 80, using HTTP protocol.
But he/she may want to configure a default telnet application when connecting via TCP port 23, using TELNET protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ReadToEnd will wait until the connection is closed. However it doesnt appear to close. You should continuously read it instead. Then it will work as you may expect.

```
//Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
var bufout = new byte[1024];
int readlen=0;
do
{
    readlen = ns.Read(bufout, 0, bufout.Length);
    Console.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufout, 0, readlen));
} while (readlen != 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using System.Net.WebClient instead of System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient directly:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            Console.WriteLine("[requesting...]");
            Console.WriteLine(wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.com"));
            Console.WriteLine("[done!]");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - Thanks but i **MUST** use TcpClient because i want to do this in lower level.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - So this is not an answer to the question and just distract others because they think "he has a answer"  :/

Comment: @isaac - If you must use TcpClient, then you really need to read the actual HTTP specs at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt.  Your original reading code will NOT work in many situations, as ReadToEnd() is the wrong way to handle them, like Aziz said earlier.